# Reading complex structures with streams

Tags: c++, iostream

Consider I have the following "pair of floats" object input format: (first variable, second variable) e.g. (1.0, 15.6).

What's the best way reading such structures? In C I would use scanf("(%f, %f)", &var1, &var2) - pretty nice, isn't it?(yes, I know it doesn't provide type safety and so on)

But I know only one way to do that using C++ streams:

```
float var1, var2;
char tmp;
cin >> tmp;
cin >> var1;
cin >> tmp;
cin >> var2;
cin >> tmp;
```

Seems ugly, and it's just a pair of floats. So, is there an elegant way to do that? Like

```
cin >> "(" >> var1 >> ", " >> var2 >> ")";
```

Comment: You should check out boost::spirit

Comment: You can also have a look in `<complex>` which has exactly such an extractor, for std::complex.

Comment: @bo thx, but I'm asking for a general case.

Comment: @karlicoss - I just thought you could be "inspired" by seeing an extractor for the format `(real, imag)`. It is using two comma separated floating point values within a set of parenthesis...

Comment: "In C I would use `scanf("(%f, %f)", &var1, &var2)` - pretty nice, isn't it?" no it isn't. Though UNIX philosophy dictates that data should be stored in text files, that's not really a clever way to do it – not when it comes to complex data structures, as C++' object-oriented features allow us to use. Consider binary files instead. And do use custom reading operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write an input operator:
Stealing FloatPair from @Seth Carnegie.

Thus input now looks normal:

```
FloatPair c;
std::cin >> c;
```

I would make it look like this.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, FloatPair& out)
{
    return stream >> I('(') >> out.a >> I(',') >> out.b >> I(')');
}
```

Then I have an ignore object like this.
It is simple to templatise if you wish. And to make the code slightly easier I call mine `I`

```
template<typename T>
struct ignore
{
    T ignoreItem;
    ignore(T const& x): ignoreItem(x) {}
};
template<typename T>
ignore<T> I(T const& x) { return ignore<T>(x);}  // This is where I in the above code comes from.
```

Then the input operator>> for the ignore looks like this.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, ignore<T> const& test)
{
    T   next;
    if ((stream >> next) && (test.ignoreItem != next))       // if the stream already failed
    {    stream.setstate(std::ios::badbit);                 // then don't change anything
    }                                                       // as it may confuse people
    return stream;
}
```

A specialization for string. To handle the fact that operator>> on string only reads a word.
Note: in scanf() a space matches 1 or more spaces. Thus obeys the same rule if the input string has a space in it.

```
template<>
struct ignore<std::string>
{
    std::vector<std::string> ignoreItemVector;
    ignore(std::string const& x)
    {
        // Split the input into a list of words to ignore.
        std::stringstream  words(x);
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(words),
                std::istream_iterator<std::string>(words),
                std::back_inserter(ignoreItemVector)
                );
    }
};
template<>
std::istream& operator>><std::string>(std::istream& stream, ignore<std::string> const& test)
{
    // Specifically ignore each word.
    foreach(std::string const& loop, test.ignoreItemVector)
    {
        std::string   next;
        if ((stream >> next) && (loop != next))       // if the stream already failed
        {    stream.setstate(std::ios::badbit);      // then don't change anything
        }                                            // as it may confuse people
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: great, I've thought about something similar, but haven't guessed to wrap char into another object.

Comment: also it can be generalized to ignore strings and then it will be completely awesome

Comment: @karlicoss: All other types are fine. But string is a tricky one. You have to watch that the operator >> for string only reads a word at a time. So you need a specialization that stores the string as a set of words and makes sure that each word is parsed correctly. Note in the C scanf() a space matches 1 or more spaces on the input So I would be good keeping that definition here.

Comment: @karlicoss be careful if you go with this solution (but if you do, mark it as the answer) because you can have a bunch of garbage in the input and it will still work: `I will gladly pay you 2sday for a hamburger 2day` is valid input, and if you didn't want that to be discarded, you're screwed.

Comment: @Martin If I do that char-by-char, everything will be fine(except a space won't be treated as 1 or more spaces). Or not..?

Comment: @karlicoss: The problem is the stream operators >> already ignore spaces. So you can't explicitly check for them. SO doing I(' ') will always fail as the stream drops spaces before trying to read anything.

Answer (score 2):

Probably [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) is the closest thing you can find. Here is [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/complex___our_first_complex_parser.html) how to use it to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: I've used Spirit for writing a calculator. But using it for reading two floats seems redundant :)

Comment: @karlicoss: well, it was intended to be an alternative for `scanf`.

Comment: I agree, boost, not to mention spirit, seems like mega overkill for this.

Comment: Boost::Spirit is definitely way too much for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is create a class representing a pair of floats:

```
class FloatPair {
public:
    FloatPair() : a(), b() { }

    float a, b;
};
```

And overload `operator>>` to work with streams:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& rhs, FloatPair& out) {
    rhs.ignore(256, '(');
    rhs >> out.a;
    rhs.ignore(256, ' ');
    rhs >> out.b;
    rhs.ignore(256, ')');

    return rhs;
}
```

So you can just stream in a `FloatPair`:

```
FloatPair fp1, fp2;
cin >> fp1 >> fp2;
```

This is kind of fragile though, because if you have very much deviancy from the format `(float, float)` in the input, it will break.

Comment: I think that is the opposite of fragile. I think it is robust because it will break if you input the wrong thing in the operator>> (though I would have checked the characters as they came in to make sure they were correct and set the bad bit if they were not what was expected).

Comment: Oh, thanks for `ignore`, better than defining temporary variable. Yes, I know about overloading, the point is in a possibility of changing the input format without breaking the program

Comment: @karlicoss I don't think you can change the format of the input without changing the program and recompiling in any case, whether you're using plain `istream`s or even boost::spirit. Also, the way I rewrote the `ignore`s in the update makes it where you can have things like spaces in the input like `(  2.2   ,   5.11   )`

Comment: @seth-carnegie Yes, of course, I will need to recompile, but I want to changle the code briefly, without counting an offset to start reading float correctly.

Comment: @Martin whoops, old habits and all that :)